# Moving Texture in LibGdx with increasing speed

Tags: java, libgdx

I make my texture move like decreasing its X axis. But the problem is when I moved it with a increasing speed it is not add properly. My sample code is as followed.

```
picx = 0;
newpicx = 1024;
if(speed<20) speed+=.05f;

picx -=speed;
newpicx -= speed;

if ((picx + 1024 - speed-4) <0) {
    picx = 1024;
}

if ((newpicx + 1024 - speed-4) <0) {
    newpicx = 1024;     
}
```

Comment: I dont know what is going wrong

Comment: We will need a bit more details here if you want help Its not clear what your problem is. What output are you getting or expecting? 

Your indentation looks kinda crazy which doesnt help. Can you edit your code to clear it up?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense but this is my attemp:

```
picx = 0;
newpicx = 1024;
if(speed<20) speed+=.05f;

picx -=speed;
newpicx -= speed;

if ((picx + 1024 - speed-4) <0) {
    picx = 1024;
}

if ((newpicx + 1024 - speed-4) <0) {
    newpicx = 1024;     
}
```

You are making two "pic"s whatever that is,and their x position start 1st=0, 2nd=1024. Then you are moving them left (negative x) using an increasing speed that stabilizes at 20, and when they are at more then 1024 units below 0 in the x axis,they teleport to positive 1024.

Then you have problems when you start increasing their x,instead of decreasing. Thats because you aren't handling when they are +1024 units positive x.

```
picx +=speed*delta; //use delta for FrameIndependant Movement
newpicx += speed*delta;

if (picx > 1024){
    picx = -1024;
}

if (newpicx > 1024){
    newpicx = -1024;     
}
```